# How to reverse sign extension?

Tags: assembly, x86-64, att

I have multiplied two numbers with `imulq`. It returns a signed number on `rdx:rax`. I want to compress this into the `rax` register. Basically, I am looking for the instruction that reverses `cqo`.

Comment: You seem to have misunderstood how [two's complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) works. It's not a sign bit followed by a magnitude.

Comment: @Michael Ok I see. Removed that part.

Comment: How do you want to handle overflow—I mean, if the result doesn’t fit in rax? If you’re sure it won’t overflow, then either (a) just use rax; or (b) use `imul rax, <src>`, which is faster because it doesn’t have to compute the full 128-bit result. Either way, the result is in rax.

Comment: @prl It can overflow. If it does, what do I do? What would happen in another language in case of an overflow with signed multiplication? Should I just take rax anyways?

Comment: In C, overflow would be undefined behavior. In some other languages, it would throw an exception. In assembly, you have the advantage that you can handle it however you want according to your program’s requirements.

Comment: I think that I will just return rax in the case of overflow

Comment: @prl The lower 64-bits will be the same with imul and imulq right? I'll use imul then so I can check for overflow more simply.

Comment: There's no difference between imul and imulq. The destination register size indicates the size of the multiply, so imulq is redundant. The difference I am suggesting is the two-operand form of imul instead the one-operand form. Only the one-operand form generates a 128-bit result. The lower 64 bits are the same for both.

Comment: Why is this tagged `gcc`?  There's no mention of inline asm in C.  I think `att` and/or `gnu-assembler` tags seem more appropriate.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the result fits in 64 bits, then rax already contains the 64-bit result and you don't need to do anything to get the result into the rax register.
However, if you only need a 64-bit result, then you should use the two-operand form of the instruction, `imul rax, <src>`, which is faster because it doesn’t have to compute the full 128-bit result.

If you want to handle error on overflow, then use `jo <error-handler>` after the multiply to check for a result that doesn't fit in 64 bits. This works with either the single-operand form of imul, which generates a 128-bit result, and with the two- or three-operand forms, which generate a 64-bit result. But if you intend to discard the upper 64 bits even when there's an overflow, then there's no reason to use that form of the instruction.